# Event PCP IDs mismatch in the civicrm_pcp_block table

Tags: civievent, pcp

An oddity discovered in WP/CiviCRM 5.70.0: an **Event** "Personal Campaign" tab  displays non-editable fields
[image]

- Campaign Type "Contribution" (mustn't be "Event" ? )
- Online Contribution Page : empty (supposed to allow an Event selection I believe )

---

Partially confirmed on the https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ - the tab comes empty & with the infamous "Network Error Unable to reach the server " message.
[image: wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org]

A temporary band-aid:in the "civicrm_pcp_block" table, find the block corresponded with the event and manually change the "target_entity_id" from "contribute" to "event" (the "contribute" appears to be the default choice for every "event" record in the table).

This makes the  "Online Contribution Page" label disappear and fixes the rest of it.

Possible related deprecation message:

```
[warning] attempt to access invalid property :_eventId Caller: CRM_Core_Form::getVar
Array
(
[civi.tag] => deprecated
)
```

Answer (score 0):

A temporary band-aid:in the "civicrm_pcp_block" table, find the block corresponded with the event and manually change the "target_entity_id" from "contribute" to "event" (the "contribute" appears to be the default choice for every "event" record in the table).

This makes the "Online Contribution Page" label disappear and fixes the rest of it.

Comment: If you're getting the same thing on wpdemo, please create an issue at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues describing your problem and your solution.  And if you can, a PR would be great